# Command invoked by eclipse to compile Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem with my Eclipse Kepler installation, which is an EE build.

I would not like to work with it anymore but, for me to work manually without any IDE, I would like to know what commands it invokes to compile the source code and put all the folders and manifests together.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to work without an IDE then i suggest you start using a build tool either [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for that. Otherwise you could just compile everything using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) and use the standard java tools to make your project and build a [war](http://premaseem.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/create-war-using-command-prompt/), but that would make your life a living hell :)